# Keyboard events

Tags: jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

How do I call a `click` event of the link, when some keyboard button is pressed?

I would like to **call a next/previous page** on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey){
     if(e.keyCode == 37){
        //ctrl + leftbutton pressed
        $("a.prevButton").trigger("click");
     }else if(e.keyCode == 39){
        //ctrl + rightbutton pressed
        $("a.nextButton").trigger("click");
     }
  }
});
```

[fiddle it live](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JypsS/)

Comment: this + `$('#previous').trigger('click');`  (if the previous link got `id="previous"` of course)

Comment: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx is what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        document.getElementById("prevButton").click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        document.getElementById("nextButton").click();
    }
  }
});
```

code 37 is for left arrow & code 39 for right arrow

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using a library called jquery.hotkeys, found here: http://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys . If not using the library itself, the source code can give you an idea of what needs to be done.

[Disclaimer: I found this library via searching, and have not used it nor tested it myself. Use at your own discretion.]

Answer (score 1):

just use this plugin with jQuery and you can set up key combinations for shortcuts: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys.

you can set up shortcuts like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            shortcut("Ctrl+Right",function() {
            document.getElementById("your next button ID").click();
        });
        shortcut("Ctrl+Left",function() {
        document.getElementById("your prev button ID").click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this w/ jQuery [but i'm sure it'll be very simple].

In terms of pure javascript, you can get the link's reference using `document.getElementById`. Then retrieve its `href` attribute using `.href`. Lastly, change the document's location to the href location -> `document.location = href`

if you don't want a redirection, then set the form's `action` attribute and do `form.submit()`